# How to Convert Html Table to Jquery Table dynamically?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am new to jQuery. I need to generate table dynamically in jQuery.

Is there any tool available for jQuery to generate an Html table? How can I convert table in html code into jQuery?

Comment: What is a "jQuery table"? I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

```
var $table = $("<table></table>");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#your_html_element_id').after
  ('<table><tr><td>...</td></tr><tr><td>...</td></tr></table>');
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got a feeling that you want to create a data grid out of your table using a jquery widget. If that's the case, the first thing you need to do is learn to write more descriptive questions :)

The second thing to do is to search for jquery data grids. http://bit.ly/JPqUBb

I've had good luck with ingrid, flexigrid, and jqgrid in the past, all are very simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

For creating tables using JQuery, I recommend using the datatables plugin:

```
http://datatables.net/
```

It's got lots of functionality and the documentation is great.